# Converting TIFF to JPG via Imagick - Terrible Result

Tags: php, imagemagick, imagick

Source image:

[image: SOURCE]

My Code:

```
$mgck_wnd = new Imagick();
$mgck_wnd->readImageBlob($file);
// 1 cmyk2rgb
$img_colspc = $mgck_wnd->getImageColorspace();
if ($img_colspc != imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB && $img_colspc != imagick::COLORSPACE_GRAY) {
    $profiles = $mgck_wnd->getImageProfiles('*', false); // get profiles
    $has_icc_profile = (array_search('icc', $profiles) !== false); // we're interested if ICC
    if ($has_icc_profile === false) {
        // image does not have CMYK ICC profile, we add one
        $icc_cmyk = file_get_contents('icc/Generic CMYK Profile.icc');
        $mgck_wnd->profileImage('icc', $icc_cmyk);
    }
    // Then we need to add RGB profile
    $icc_rgb = file_get_contents('icc/Generic RGB Profile.icc');
    $mgck_wnd->profileImage('icc', $icc_rgb);
    $mgck_wnd->setImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
}
// 2 to300dpi
$img_units = $mgck_wnd->getImageUnits();
switch ($img_units) {
    case imagick::RESOLUTION_UNDEFINED: $units= 'undefined'; break;
    case imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH: $units= 'PPI'; break;
    case imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERCENTIMETER: $units= 'PPcm'; break;
}
list($x_res, $y_res) = $mgck_wnd->getImageResolution();
if ($x_res == 300 && $y_res == 300 && $img_units == imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH) { return null; }
$mgck_wnd->setResolution(300, 300);
$mgck_wnd->setImageUnits(imagick::RESOLUTION_PIXELSPERINCH);

// 3 tiff2jpg
$img_colspc = $mgck_wnd->getImageColorspace();
if ($img_colspc == imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB) {
    $mgck_wnd->setImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
}
$mgck_wnd->setCompression(Imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
$mgck_wnd->setCompressionQuality(85);
$mgck_wnd->setImageFormat('jpeg');
return $mgck_wnd;
```

Result image:

[image: RESULT]

How to fix it?

Tiff Image Example from https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff
Color Profiles from https://github.com/gopalkoduri/DLIdownloader/tree/master/libs/tiff2pdf

Comment: NO! I use examples from this answer and have terrible result!

Comment: Although we can pick the image from your question to test your code, we haven't got the color profile files. The image in the question is also not CMYK. Whether it was converted by SO, or the cause of your problem, I can't tell. As it stands, [your problem is not reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Update post with links

Comment: Thank you for the update. Regrettably I cannot read TIFF files with my installation. But anybody else, who can read those files, can now test your code.

Comment: If I use `identify file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff` in Imagemagick, it says "Not a TIFF or MDI file, bad magic number". So apparently something is corrupt. My GraphicConverter also says it is corrupt. Same for my Photoshop

Comment: Your link to color profiles are not color profiles!

Comment: @fmw42 `file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff` is properly identified as TIFF for me by both `file` and `identify`. MD5: df87217e2c181ae6674898dff27e5a56

Comment: @Xenoid.  Can you open it or use identify in Imagemagick to get the listing?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Size 1131930. Hex dump starts with `49 49 2A 00` which is correct for a little-endian TIFF according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#In_files).

Comment: @fmw42 link to color profiles correct - it's folder with many profiles. You can download one by one.

Comment: Sorry, the browser I was using did not access the link properly. I got it fine using another browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Problem was in corrupted ImageMagick 6.9 library.

1. I compile lib from source via instruction https://imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php
2. And then compile Imagick module for PHP from source too https://pecl.php.net/package/imagick/3.7.0 ("./configure --with-imagick=/usr/local")
   And all works!

Answer (score 2):

Your Tiff file converts fine for me on Imagemagick 6.9.12-66 Q16.

```
convert file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff -density 300 file_example_TIFF_1MB.jpg
```

or as

```
convert file_example_TIFF_1MB.tiff -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/USWebCoatedSWOP.icc -profile /Users/fred/images/profiles/sRGB.icc -density 300 file_example_TIFF_1MB_v2.jpg
```

[image]

What is your version of Imagemagick and also the version of Imagick and your platform?

Also note that your tiff is already sRGB and not CMYK. If you add a CMYK profile, it could mess up your image colors.

Comment: Huh... CentOS 8 STream, PHP 8.1, ImageMagick 6.9.12-64 Q16 x86_64 174, pecl module v3.7.0

Comment: Version of Imagemagick is fine. How about your version of Imagick. Is that current.  Perhaps it is the issue and has some bugs or your code is faulty. Try simplifying your script and see if that works. Try PHP exec() to see if PHP is running the Imagemagick command line properly and converting your image. It is possible it is a bug in your versions of libtiff or libjpeg. Are they current?